# Mounting or file mapping into Quarkus app testcontainer during dev mode

Tags: java, containers, quarkus

I'm building an application which needs to read from files mounted to it.

This is obviously all fine when the application runs in a kubernetes type environment, but what if I want to do manual testing in dev mode. How do I mount some files from my resources project folder, or copy them into the container or make some kind of mapping?

I haven't been able to find any indication of how this could be possible, but I imagine that such a feature must exist...

Note: I'm not interested in mounting the files into of the devservices, like the database container etc. I'm only talking about the application container.

Comment: Which application ctonainer are you talking about? Quarkus does not launch your application in a container when in dev mode.

Comment: Oh right, wow, I hadn't realized. That means that java.nio.file.Path.of("./") is the root of my project, and I can use Quarkus profiles to set this path differently from when it is in fact packaged into a container. Thanks and sorry for the misunderstanding :)